# Flask blueprint inheritance

Tags: flask, routes

I have a base class called ApplicationController that looks like:

```
class ApplicationController():
    @application_controller.before_request
    def verify_auth():
        if g.authenticated == False:
            return send_to_login('You must be logged in to continue')
```

I am wondering how to use inheritance with flask blueprints.  I'd like to have sub classes inherit from ApplicationController so that the verify_auth method is run on every request to every sub controller of ApplicationController

So an example AdvertiserReportsController would look like this and would run ApplicationController's verify_auth method on every request to the AdvertiserReportsController:

```
class AdvertiserReportsController(ApplicationController):

    @advertiser_reports.route('/some/route')
    def some_route():
        return jsonify({ 'success' : True })
```

However the verify_auth method is not run on every request to the AdvertiserReportsController despite the inheritance.  Also both classes have their blueprints registered with the app.

So now I end up adding the verify_auth method to ever controller with the .before_request method...  This is repetitive and seems wrong..

```
class AdvertiserReportsController(ApplicationController):

    @advertiser_reports.before_request
    def verify_auth():
        if g.authenticated == False:
            return send_to_login('You must be logged in to continue')

    @advertiser_reports.route('/some/route')
    def some_route():
        return jsonify({ 'success' : True })
```

Comment: Decorators are applied *before the class is built*. This means that for most Flask decorators you really should not be using classes, as you are effectively registering functions, not methods.

Comment: If you want to use classes, you should be looking into [*Pluggable Views*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/) instead. They won't make working with blueprints all that much easier however.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but take a look at [flask-classy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/).